# TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes

Tags: python, unicode

I'm having a bit of trouble finding my error. When I try to run the code I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PC/Documents/Python_Projects/Segundo Teste/Game.py", line 133, in <module>
    set_message(message)
  File "C:/Users/PC/Documents/Python_Projects/Segundo Teste/Game.py", line 61, in set_message
    message = font.render(text, True, black, white)
TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes
```

These are the code lines:

```
if message != previous_message:
   set_message(message) --> line 133

def set_message(text):
  global message, previous_messsage
  message = font.render(text, True, black, white) --> line 61
  previous_messsage = message
```

Comment: Why are you setting `previous_messsage` from `font.render()`? It is **not the same variable** as `previous_message` (note the number of `s` characters in `message`).

Comment: Whatever you're passing to set_message() must not be a string. Try printing it at the beginning of the method: `print "Message: '{}' ({})".format(message, type(message))`

Comment: What is `font` here? Is this Pygame code?

Comment: Are you running python 2.*? If so, did you check whether it's a unicode string? If not convert it using unicode()

Comment: @isset: that's a red herring. The OP is using the return value of `font.render()`, which in Pygame is a `Surface` object, not a string (bytes or unicode).

Comment: `previous message` is supposed to be a variable for me to change and get track of message. I got it, it was the extra **s**. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [`Font.render()` method](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render) returns a Pygame `Surface` instance. From the documentation:

> **render()**
>   *Return rendered text as a surface*
>   `render(text, fgcolor=None, bgcolor=None, style=STYLE_DEFAULT, rotation=0, size=0) -> (Surface, Rect)`
>
> Returns a new `Surface`, with the text rendered to it in the color given by ‘fgcolor’.

You are trying to render that `Surface` instance; it is not text and not unicode. It is not clear what you expect `previous_message` to be but what you are doing won't work.

I'm ignoring your variable typo here; `previous_messsage` is not the same name as `previous_message`; the latter is spelled correctly, but you use the former in `set_message()`.